# Recover Lost Partitions Windows 10

Tags: windows, partitioning, recovery

I make one partition in my External Hard Drive and then make Windows 10 Bootable USB in the same partition, after that I lost my other drives data from the same hard disk how I can recover the lost partitions?

Comment: Windows 10 /  11 makes 3 partitions:  UEFI, Recovery and Data.  What are you trying to do?   Can you start again properly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Closed?! That wiki that's pointed to is a far cry from an accurate answer IMO. Pretending it answers each and every data recovery related issue is a mistake.